# GRPC server with spring boot on pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, grpc, grpc-java

I am able to set up standalone GRPC ( in Java) server on pods and its communicating with my local GRPC (nodejs) client over http2.

Now as a next step - I am trying to set up GRPC server + spring boot on our pods -

1. Do I have to start spring boot and GRPC as two separate processes on different ports ?  Limitation on pod is if I start main process (Spring boot process in this case ?) I can not start child process (GRPC server in this case ?)another process on a different port.
2. How can I ensure that the spring boot + grpc server communicates over http2

I see documentation with spring boot + eureka server + grpc but need to understand above details to proceed.

Comment: Please share your experiences as I believe this would be common scenario

Comment: I also have a question that - If I start embedded GRPC server along with spring boot how can I start on a secure port ? Why I need this is because my Load balancer talks to the server on port 8443 on pod so I need to start my grpc server on 8443.  My ultimate goal is to use grpc for micro services and hence need to understand how it will fit into my infra set up

Comment: please let me know if this is not the right forum to raise questions of this nature ?

Comment: please let me know if any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

1. You can start spring-boot and GRPC in the one process and listening different ports at the same time.
2. gRPC server communicates over http2 if you start the gRPC server by `io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder`

You can see the project in https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter